Rotation of a Regular $n$-gon
I saw the following claim: For a regular $n$-gon ($n \geq 3$) with vertices $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$, a rotation by angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ can be written as the composition of reflection with respect to the perpendicular bisector of $A_1A_3$ and the reflection with respect to the perpendicular bisector of $A_2A_3$.
I could prove it by bashing out which point gets mapped to which. However, is there a more intuitive/elegant way of proving/explaining why it is true?

Hint: A reflection about the axis perpendicular to $A_kA_l$ maps indices $i\mapsto k+l-i!\pmod n$, since it switches $k$ and $l$. Take the composition of both of your reflections and see what that does to the indices.

Not an answer but a reflection reverses orientation and a rotation preserves it. Hence, any combination of two reflections preserves orientation and is a rotation.

For center $O$ of the circle circumscribing the $n$-gon, a rotation of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ on $O$ maps the $n$-gon to itself (vertex $A_i \rightarrow A_{i+1}$). The piece you may be missing is that for any two lines meeting at a point ($O$) at angle $\alpha$, a reflection across the first and then second produces a rotation of $2\alpha$ about $O$ (prove this by isosceles triangles). So you need to find any two lines intersecting at $O$ subtending half of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.
Given some (isosceles) sequence $A_iA_{i+1}A_{i+2}$ you have perpendicular bisectors of $A_iA_{i+1}$ and $A_{i+1}A_{i+2}$ meeting at $O$ with angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, twice the angle we need. To get half that angle, bisect $A_iA_{i+2}$.
An easier way to state the problem would have been: a line $OA_i$, together with the adjacent perpendicular bisector of $A_iA_{i \pm 1}$, meet at $O$ at angle $\frac{\pi}{n}$, hence reflection across both lines is a rotation on $O$ of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and maps the $n$-gon to itself.
